# Successfully converts to binary on odd numbers, fails on even numbers

Tags: java, recursion, binary

I have an issue with my Java program. I made a program that takes an integer and converts it to it's value in binary. When the number is odd, there aren't any problems. 15 converts to 1111, 17 converts to 10001 and so on. The issue comes when the number is even. If I put in 16, 18, 20, etc, it just returns 0. Every time. Also, important to note that I get my number by using a recursive method that stops once it arrives at it's number.

Here's my code. Appreciate any help I can get, even if it doesn't solve the problem.

```
public class binaryConverter {
    static int nr = 16;
    static int max = 0;
    static int[] bin;
    static int[] array;
    static int finalBin;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        maxFinder();    
        binMaker();     
        toBinary(array, 0,true);
    }

    //finds out how many binary numbers are used in order to decide what length to make the array, 
    //15 = 1111, 10000 = 16 15<16
    private static void maxFinder(){    
        for(int i = 0, n = 1; i<nr; i++){
            if(n>nr){
                max = i;
                break;
            }
            n*=2;       //n doubles for every i loop, starts with one
        }
    }

    //makes a library of standard to binary (0 = 1, 1 = 2; 2 = 4; 3 = 8...)
    private static void binMaker(){     
        int[] temp = new int[max];
        for(int i = 0; i<temp.length; i++){
            if(i == 0) temp[i] = 1;
            else temp[i]=2*temp[i-1];
        }
        bin = temp;
        array = new int[bin.length];
    }

    //adds the array together in order to access what number the array currently resembles in binary
    private static int sum(int[] ar, int length){
        int sum = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i<=length; i++) if(ar[i]==1) sum += bin[i];
        return sum;
    }

    //loops until the array becomes the number in binary
    private static void toBinary(int[] ar, int i, boolean one){     //i = the current number it's on, eg. 10i01, i is the third slot
        if(i==array.length) return;     //break if 
        ar[i] = (one) ? 1:0;
        if(sum(ar, i)==nr){     //if the temporary array is the number but in binary ...
            array = ar;     //turns the static array into the temporary array
            String temp = "";
            for(int z = 0; z<array.length; z++) temp += array[z];
            finalBin = Integer.parseInt(temp);  //makes finalBin represent the original number but in binary
            return;
        }
        else{   //else go to the next slot
            toBinary(ar, i+1, true);
            toBinary(ar, i+1, false);   
        }
    }
}
```

Edit: I have now added the following line to my main:
   if(finalBin != nr) toBinary(array,0,false);
        System.out.println(finalBin);
This is to make sure that it can start with 0 aswell. However, I still get the incorrect answer, as it gives me pretty seemingly random returns on even numbers.

Comment: What happened when you tried debugging?

Comment: The array turned to {1,0,0,0,0}..., that is, it went a full loop until all of them had turned into 1s and then 0s

Comment: To calculate the number of needed binary places (`maxFinder`) you could use the log function instead... Do you have to do it in a recursive way? There are much smarter solutions for this: https://www.cs.indiana.edu/cgi-pub/c211/snake/

Comment: Oh right! I forget about converting to binary base using log. Thanks for that! However, it's not that I have to do it using recursion, it's that I want to improve my recursion skills.

Comment: This is somewhat convoluted and therefore hard to understand and hard to get right. Go for a simpler method!

Comment: Basically this is a bruteforce approach which is going through all possibilities until it finds the right representation of the decimal number which is not very efficient...

Answer (score 0):

You starting you recursion always with a one at the first place of the binary:

```java
toBinary(array, 0, true);
```

This way you never can get an even number. An even number always has a zero at the "first" bit (representing "2 to the power of 0").

You could start the recursion like so:

```java
toBinary(array, 0, true);

if (/* not found a solution */)
   toBinary(array, 0, false);
```

Comment: Ah, yes. I  didn't think of that. I've changed my and now I don't get 0s anymore, except that I still get incorrect numbers. 2 gives 0, 4 gives 1, 6 gives 11, 8 gives 1.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code as converter and replace `String` type to some `List`:

```
public static String decToBin(int value) {
    String result = "";
    while (value > 1) {
        result += value % 2;
        value /= 2;
    }
    result += value;
    result = new StringBuilder(result)
            .reverse()
            .toString();
    return result;
}
```

Comment: What would this accomplish?

Comment: Convert integer to `string binary text` or to `binary list` like a `[0,1,1,0,0]`

Comment: Ah, I see. But the issue I have is not to convert to binary, but to convert to binary using recursion. The whole point is to practice recursion.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you could get it to work:

```
public class binaryConverter {
    static int nr = 16;
    static int max = 0;
    static int[] bin;
    static int[] array;
    static int finalBin;
    static boolean foundSolution = false;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        maxFinder();
        binMaker();
        toBinary(array, 0, true);

        if (!foundSolution)
            toBinary(array, 0, false);

        for (int i = array.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            System.out.print(array[i]);
        System.out.println();
    }

    //finds out how many binary numbers are used in order to decide what length to make the array,
    //15 = 1111, 10000 = 16 15<16
    private static void maxFinder(){
        for(int i = 0, n = 1; i<nr; i++){
            if(n>nr){
                max = i;
                break;
            }
            n*=2;       //n doubles for every i loop, starts with one
        }
    }

    //makes a library of standard to binary (0 = 1, 1 = 2; 2 = 4; 3 = 8...)
    private static void binMaker(){
        int[] temp = new int[max];
        for(int i = 0; i<temp.length; i++){
            if(i == 0) temp[i] = 1;
            else temp[i]=2*temp[i-1];
        }
        bin = temp;
        array = new int[bin.length];
    }

    //adds the array together in order to access what number the array currently resembles in binary
    private static int sum(int[] ar, int length){
        int sum = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i<=length; i++) if(ar[i]==1) sum += bin[i];
        return sum;
    }

    //loops until the array becomes the number in binary
    private static void toBinary(int[] ar, int i, boolean one){     //i = the current number it's on, eg. 10i01, i is the third slot
        if(i==array.length || foundSolution) return;     //break if
        ar[i] = (one) ? 1:0;
        if(sum(ar, i)==nr){     //if the temporary array is the number but in binary ...
            array = ar;     //turns the static array into the temporary array
            String temp = "";
            for(int z = 0; z<array.length; z++) temp += array[z];
            finalBin = Integer.parseInt(temp);  //makes finalBin represent the original number but in binary
            foundSolution = true;
            return;
        }
        else{   //else go to the next slot
            toBinary(ar, i+1, true);
            toBinary(ar, i+1, false);
        }
    }
}
```